# Flutter app not running on device, console says otherwise? What could be the issue?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio to test an application. My device shows up in the Flutter Device Selection. Upon running the app, the console says:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ANE LX1 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

I'm not seeing any errors.

Unfortunately, nothing happens on my device. I followed the flutter installation guide from docs.flutter.dev, not sure what else I can do to get it to work.

Do you have any idea what might be causing this issue? Thanks!

I tried testing a flutter app on my phone. I expected it to run on my phone, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

first start your emulator, once it is started just type on terminal flutter run, instead of running it from the run button.

Comment: I am looking to test on my actual phone, not on the emulator

Comment: then it will take a while to get installed in your phone, make sure that you are not running the project on emulator via different IDE, and from the Android Studio you are trying to run it on physical device. apart from that, before getting installed in your phone, it will give a pop window 10 sec to install the app, make sure to do that

Comment: you were right about it taking a while. it tooks several minutes and came up with an error. thanks for the advice.